# android make video of screen -need to take application video

Tags: android, video, record

In one of my application i need to record video of my own screen.

I need to make a video in that user can take video of their app how it possible?
first question is it possible so? if yes then how? any useful links or some help

Thanks
Pragna Bhatt

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but with certain limitations. I have done it in one of my projects.

1. Android 4.4 adds support for screen recording. [See here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-screen-recording)
2. If you are targeting lower versions, you can achieve it, but it will be slow. There is no direct or easy way to do it. What you will do is, create drawable from your view/layout. Convert that drawable to YUV format and send it to camera (see some library where you can give custom yuv image to camera), camera will play it like a movies, you can save that movies to storage. Use threads to increase frame-rate (new multi-core device will have high frame-rate).

Only create drawable (from view) when there is any change in view or its children, for that you can use `Global Layout Listener`. Otherwise send same YUV image to camera.

**Limitation:**

1. You can not create video of more than one activities (at a time), or their transactions, because you are creating image from view. (Work on it yourself, may be you'll find a way)
2. You can not increase frame rate from a certain point, because it depends on hardware of your device.

Comment: i want to specify that i want to app like multiple images then i user swipe image and can draw on image this hole activity i want to record as video is it possible?

Comment: yes, you can capture image from parent view (which will have viewpager etc), and it will detect change in view when user swipes. So, your swipe will also show in video